# Connecting to server farm. SharePoint 2013

Tags: server-farm, farm

I have 4 VMs

1. ADVM (Active Directory/Domain)
2. SPVM (Sharepoint Server)
3. SQLVM (SQL Server)
4. SPVM2 (New Sharepoint Server that I will connect to my previous farm that I created in SPVM)

VMs 2 and 3 is smoothly running, then I created VM4(SPVM2), and successfully connect it to my Server Farm that created using my VM2(SPVM), now that I connect my VM4 to the farm, I delete my VM2 because I will use my VM4 as the Main server and dispose the VM2.

My problem now is everytime I access my SharePoint site, it shows me that **the page cant be displayed Make sure the web address is correct**

I'm wondering why because as far as I know, it will get the information on SQL Server that's why I thought that deleting my VM2 won't affect the service.

Comment: is this for all the sites? did you update your AAM settings? if you are using the DNS, then make sure now they are pointing to the new VM. when you delete the old VM, how you did, did you disconnect it via config wizard?

Comment: where can i find AAM settings? When I delete my VM, I just delete it and also to my DNS in Active Directory and Computers.

Comment: That,s not right way to delete the server from sharepoint.you have to run the configuration wizard n disconnect the server....for aam, go to central admin> application management >aam....

Comment: At first I knew that that was wrong hehe. I can't even access the Central Admin, same result as mention above. Is there a way to resolve this? Although this is only a test machine, where I can create a new one again, but I just want to see if there's an answer for this, so if in the future that I will experience this kind of problem, I already have an Idea on how to resolve it. I'm very new to this so please bear with me :)

Comment: 1st thing, run the configuration wizard on new vm n select this server ll host central admin, this way CA will back....

Comment: I re-run the configuration, but it seems that It change the sitename from SPVM:1234 to SPVM2:1234. After running the Configuration, it goes to SPVM:1234 but same error as mention above, but when I try to access SPVM2:1234, it directs me to the Initial Farm Configuration. Do I need to Start the wizard?

Comment: Yes it should change the name n point to new vm....old vm no more exisy

Comment: does it mean that I cant retrieve my old site? because I checked the site collection list, and access the sites inside it, it still shows me the same error as mention above.

Comment: all the sites in site collection is named on my previous VM.

Comment: Yes you can, as long as webapplication n dB are intact....get CA back n hopefully everything else

Comment: That is when u need to update aam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case as you add new VM and remove the old VM. You have to make sure the following things.

- make sure the Central admin is provision on new VM.(now url will be newVM:port)
- Update the DNS record to new VM
- Update the AAM settings.
- Now all URLs having the new VM in it.

When you disconnect a server from a farm please use the PSconfig Wizard it is really save you from alot of issues. you can also remove it from central admin.

[Remove a server from a farm in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263130.aspx)